# How to upgrade elastic search from 1.7.x to 7.0?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am in need of a solution to upgrade/migrate elasticsearch from 1.7.6 to 7.0 with all the data and the reports. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install elastic search 7.0 and reindex the data again.

You can't just migrate the old indexes of elastic search 1.7 to elastic search 7.0.

> Elasticsearch can read indices created in the previous major version.
>   If you have indices created in 5.x or before, you must reindex or
>   delete them before upgrading to 7.1.1. Elasticsearch nodes will fail
>   to start if incompatible indices are present. Snapshots of 5.x or
>   earlier indices cannot be restored to a 7.x cluster even if they were
>   created by a 6.x cluster.

[Refer elastic search documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html)